# asp.net 4.5 model binding

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.5

In the [what's new in ASP.NET 4.5 doc it talks about model binding in web forms](http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/whitepapers/whats-new#_Toc318097390) which I'm trying out.

I have some of it working but I'm getting a compile time error:

> 'System.Web.UI.Control' is not an attribute class

This is pointing to the word Control in this part of the code [**Control**("ddlCategory")] int? categoryId.

I'm thinking I need to add some reference but the doc doesn't mention that, so I'm not sure what's wrong.

```
public IEnumerable<Product> LoadProducts([Control("ddlCategory")] int? categoryId)
{
    var retval = new List<Product>();
    if (categoryId.HasValue)
    {
        using (var db = new DBDataContext())
        {
            retval = db.Products.Where(x => x.CategoryId == categoryId.Value).ToList();
        }
    }
    return retval;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try putting the fully-qualified name of the attribute.
So try this:

```
[System.Web.ModelBinding.Control("ddlCategory")]
```

Instead of this:

```
[Control("ddlCategory")]
```